# T-SQL: Using OVER and PARTITION BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have the following data

```
 |  Item  | Value |    Date   |
 ------------------------------
 |   1    |  10   | 01.01.2010
 |   1    |  20   | 02.01.2010
 |   1    |  30   | 03.01.2010
 |   1    |  40   | 04.01.2010
 |   1    |  50   | 05.01.2010
 |   1    |  80   | 10.01.2010
 |   2    |  30   | 04.01.2010
 |   2    |  60   | 06.01.2010
 |   2    |  70   | 07.01.2010
 |   2    |  80   | 08.01.2010
 |   2    |  100  | 09.01.2010
```

And the following statement

```
SELECT   Item, Value, MIN(Date) OVER (PARTITION BY Item) 
FROM     Data
WHERE    Value >= 50
```

And I get the following result

```
 |  Item  | Value |    Date   |
 ------------------------------
 |   1    |  50   | 05.01.2010
 |   1    |  80   | 05.01.2010
 |   2    |  60   | 06.01.2010
 |   2    |  70   | 06.01.2010
 |   2    |  80   | 06.01.2010
 |   2    |  100  | 06.01.2010
```

But what I need is this

```
 |  Item  | Value |    Date   |
 ------------------------------
 |   1    |  10   | 05.01.2010
 |   1    |  20   | 05.01.2010
 |   1    |  30   | 05.01.2010
 |   1    |  40   | 05.01.2010
 |   1    |  50   | 05.01.2010
 |   1    |  80   | 05.01.2010
 |   2    |  30   | 06.01.2010
 |   2    |  60   | 06.01.2010
 |   2    |  70   | 06.01.2010
 |   2    |  80   | 06.01.2010
 |   2    |  100  | 06.01.2010
```

Is there any quick solution to get this with one statment without a self-join?

Thank you :)

Comment: your result is wrong? i only got based on the data you provided.

1 50 2010-05-01
1 80 2010-10-01
2 60 2010-06-01
2 70 2010-07-01
2 80 2010-08-01
2       100     2010-09-01

Comment: Oh, yes sorry! I corrected it

Comment: +1 for helping me understand the over partition in SQL 2008

Answer (score 4, accepted):

without a self join, try this:

```
DECLARE @YourTable table (item int,value int, Date datetime)
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (1    ,  10   , '01/01/2010')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (1    ,  20   , '02/01/2010')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (1    ,  30   , '03/01/2010')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (1    ,  40   , '04/01/2010')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (1    ,  50   , '05/01/2010')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (1    ,  80   , '10/01/2010')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (2    ,  30   , '04/01/2010')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (2    ,  60   , '06/01/2010')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (2    ,  70   , '07/01/2010')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (2    ,  80   , '08/01/2010')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (2    ,  100  , '09/01/2010')


SELECT   Item, Value, MIN(CASE WHEN Value >= 50 THEN Date ELSE NULL END) OVER (PARTITION BY Item) 
FROM     @YourTable
```

OUTPUT:

```
Item        Value       
----------- ----------- -----------------------
1           10          2010-05-01 00:00:00.000
1           20          2010-05-01 00:00:00.000
1           30          2010-05-01 00:00:00.000
1           40          2010-05-01 00:00:00.000
1           50          2010-05-01 00:00:00.000
1           80          2010-05-01 00:00:00.000
2           30          2010-06-01 00:00:00.000
2           60          2010-06-01 00:00:00.000
2           70          2010-06-01 00:00:00.000
2           80          2010-06-01 00:00:00.000
2           100         2010-06-01 00:00:00.000
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

(11 row(s) affected)
```